# Python function to change a word from a sentense to upper case when a sentense and word are passed

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a one line function to change a word from a sentence to upper case. Please suggest.

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
    return(___)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a code writing service. Please provide some sample input, desired output and any problem you ran into.

Answer (score 2):

This should fit your requirements, using `string.replace()` and `string.upper()`.

**Code:**

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
    return sentence.replace(word, word.upper())
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> highlight_word('I like Python', 'like')
'I LIKE Python'
```

Comment: Just want to be careful with replace words coming as part of another word.